# Skip lines in std::istream

Tags: c++, istream

I'm using std::getline() to read lines from an std::istream-derived class, how can I move forward a few lines?

Do I have to just read and discard them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Edit:** You can also use std::istream::ignore, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/25012566/492336

---

> Do I have to use getline the number of lines I want to skip?

No, but it's probably going to be the clearest solution to those reading your code. If the number of lines you're skipping is large, you can improve performance by reading large blocks and counting newlines in each block, stopping and repositioning the file to the last newline's location. But unless you are having performance problems, I'd just put getline in a loop for the number of lines you want to skip.

Comment: Counting newlines is sorta what a looped `getline` would do, right?

Comment: @GMan - Save the Unicorns: Yes, but you can use larger blocks and shift forward a larger distance if you know n is large (i.e. counting more than one newline in a buffer block)

Comment: what if I'll load all the file to memory and parse it with regular expressions ? the file is less then 1MB.

Answer (score 21):

**No, you don't have to use getline**

The more efficient way is ignoring strings with **std::istream::ignore**

```
for (int currLineNumber = 0; currLineNumber < startLineNumber; ++currLineNumber){
    if (addressesFile.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), addressesFile.widen('\n'))){ 
        //just skipping the line
    } else 
        return HandleReadingLineError(addressesFile, currLineNumber);
}
```

HandleReadingLineError is not standart but *hand-made*, of course.
The first parameter is maximum number of characters to extract. If this is exactly numeric_limits::max(), there is no limit:
Link at cplusplus.com: [std::istream::ignore](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/)

If you are going to skip a lot of lines you definitely should use it instead of getline: when i needed to skip 100000 lines in my file it took about a second in opposite to 22 seconds with getline.

Answer (score 8):

Yes use `std::getline` unless you know the location of the newlines.

If for some strange reason you happen to know the location of where the newlines appear then you can use `ifstream::seekg` first.

You can read in other ways such as `ifstream::read` but `std::getline` is probably the easiest and most clear solution.

Comment: @Billy: Actually your tardiness gave me 10 extra rep since I was already at max cap until 10 min ago.

Comment: LOL! I have yet to bump my head into said cap.