# How to remove the first N lines of a std::istream (e.g. std::stringstream)?

Tags: c++, stringstream, istream

I have a `std::stringstream` and I want a `stringstream` where the first N lines are removed. How can I achieve this?

The following lines using `getline` do not work as wished.

```
std::stringstream source(...);
for (int i(0); i < N; +i)
{
    char* c;
    source.getline(c, 256);
}
std::stringstream target(source.str());
```

Comment: std::getline n times?

Comment: read the stream getline n times

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581794/c-ifstream-how-can-i-skip-forward-several-lines

Comment: @sashoalm not "similar"; an outright duplicate. (Yes, they differ in that the other one is about `fstream`, but that doesn't really matter)

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I was hesitating whether to mark it as such because the other is about ifstream not stringstream. Dunno if it qualifies as 'exact'...

Comment: @sashoalm considering the fact that the solution is exactly the same, I'd say yes.

Comment: FWIW, it's Arthur P. Golubev's answer to "2581794" that mentions ignore, which is the best all round approach.  Re closing this as a duplicate... could edit the title to say `istream (e.g. std::stringstream)`....

Comment: @TonyD [Absolutely](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore). Why store data you're not going to use?